# ASPNET MVC Custom route fails with "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Home'."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to create a custom route to handle a specific url with multiple parameters.  I have added a new new route definition to the global.asax but when I try to navigate to the action I get the error message "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Home'."

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "HomeDetails",
      routeTemplate: "Home/Detail/{articleId}/{articleVersion}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Detail", articleId = "0", articleVersion = "0.0" }
  );

  //routes.MapHttpRoute(
  //    name: "DefaultApi",
  //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  //);

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

  public ViewResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  public ViewResult Detail(int articleId, decimal articleVersion)
  {
  // does stuff here...
  return View(model);
  }

}
```

The url I'm trying to hit would be something like `http://localhost/home/detail/1234/1.2`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`MapHttpRoute` routes to a Web API controller inheriting `ApiController`.

In your example HomeController inherits the standard `Controller` (not ApiController), you need to use `MapRoute` instead for the controller to be found:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "HomeDetails",
  url: "Home/Detail/{articleId}/{articleVersion}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Detail", articleId = 0, articleVersion = 0.0 }
);
```

Comment: Doh! Absolutely spot on.  Thanks  :)

Comment: ...that would be why the error message was returned as an xml document...**wanders off feeling slightly stupid**

Comment: That saved the day for me pjumble. I spent the last 2 days trying to figure out what was going on. Thanks!

Comment: The URL mapping is totally counter-intuitive. Even worse is the error report!

Answer (score 0):

hi code change like this.

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "HomeDetails",
      routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{articleId}/{articleVersion}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Detail", articleId = "0", articleVersion = "0.0" }
  );
```